# SSL error while trying to make an https connection using websocket-client

Tags: python, ssl, websocket

I'm trying to write a websocket program in python that listens to server messages and prints them. Since I am new to websockets, I tried to start by using the code given on the [websocket-client](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client) github page. Particularly the javascript like API. However, I get this error:

> [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

I want to work with https, but I don't want the ssl verification failing to flag an error. I tried to search for ways in which I could specify this in the program, but I couldn't find any literature on this. Please help!

```
class websocketIO:
    def __init__(self, protocol, host, port):
        self.ws = None
        self.openCallback = None
        self.protocol = "ws"
        if protocol == "https:":
            self.protocol = "wss"
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.messages = {}


    def open(self, callback):
        print self.protocol + "://" + self.host + ":" + self.port
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.protocol + "://" + self.host + ":" + self.port, on_message = self.on_message, on_error = self.on_error, on_close = self.on_close)
        self.openCallback = callback
        self.ws.on_open = self.on_open;
        self.ws.run_forever()

    def on_open(self, ws):
        threading.start_new_thread(self.openCallback, ())

    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        if isinstance(message, str):
            msg = json.loads(message)
            if msg['func'] in self.messages:
                self.messages[msg['func']](msg['data'])
            else:
                print "Error: message is not a binary string"

    def run(self, *args):
        self.ws.on_open = args[0]

    def on(self, name, callback):
        self.messages[name] = callback

    def emit(self, name, data):
        message = {'func': name, 'data': data}
        self.ws.send(json.dumps(message))

def main():
    global wsio
    wsio = websocketIO("https:", "localhost", "9090")
    wsio.on('setupDisplayConfiguration', setupDisplayConfiguration)
    wsio.on('initialize', initialize)
    wsio.open(on_open)

def on_open():
    global wsio
    wsio.emit('Message1', {'Test': "Data"});
    print "Message Sent"

def setupDisplayConfiguration(data):
    print (data['host'] + ":" + str(data['port']))

def initialize(data):
    print (data['address'])

main()
```

Comment: can you add some sample code?

Comment: @Rafael - I have edited and added sample code.

Comment: try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994549/how-can-i-implement-a-secure-websocket-wss-server-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You connect with your client via SSL to localhost. I doubt that you use a certificate at localhost which can be verified against your trusted CAs and also matches the hostname of localhost. Have you checked?

Comment: When I visit the index page served by my server at localhost on chrome, it doesn't complain about https. Doesn't that indicate that there is no problem with certificate being used with the server?

Comment: If chrome does not complain you either told the browser before, that it should accept this certificate or its issuer or you did not connect with https, but only with http. Because no CA should create a certificate for `localhost`. But, the browser and your script do not share the CA store, so any exceptions you've added for the browser are not automatically added for the script too.

Comment: I have modified the call for run_forever from the above code as:
`self.ws.run_forever(sslopt=dict(cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL, ca_certs=path_to_the_cert))`
Yet, there is no change in its behaviour.

Comment: If the name in the cert does not match the hostname this will not help. And making the certificate optional does not help either, this setting is usually used for having optional client certificates. But your problem is probably the server certificate - at least that's what I assume. The error message does not give much information, but that's usually the case with SSL debugging :(. You might try to use openssl s_client to getter better information for debugging.